# NSTimer initialized with fireDate does not fire

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I am trying to use an `NSTimer` to call a method, but it doesn`t work.
I need this method to be run once, at a specific date and time, which the user sets on a calendar.

I have this code in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[comps setDay:24];
[comps setMonth:10];
[comps setYear:2011];

[comps setHour:23];
[comps setMinute:11];
[comps setSecond:0];


NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
schedulerTimer=[[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date interval:0 target:self selector:@selector(recordByScheduler:) userInfo:nil repeats:false];
```

But this code does nothing. Probably I misunderstood `NSCalendar`. What should I be doing here? And a second question: is `NSTimer` fired when the application is running in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to schedule the timer in the runloop.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:schedulerTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Or similar, depending on situation.

Response to question edit:

No NSTimer is not fired when your application is in the background.

Answer (score 2):

NSTimer will not fire if your app is suspended in the background.  You might be able to use UILocalNotification depending on what you need.

Comment: Nice. Never occurred to me he might have been trying to set an alarm, and not actually want a NSTimer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by @NJones but it didn't work. With a little juggling, I found that you should use `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, not `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` on `mainRunLoop`. For example,

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:schedulerTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Or Swift, which I now use:

```
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(schedulerTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

though, it is the mode, not run loop, that prevented it from working in my case.

The document says the following:

> NSDefaultRunLoopMode
>
> The mode to deal with input sources other than NSConnection objects.
>
> This is the most commonly used run-loop mode.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> NSRunLoopCommonModes
>
> Objects added to a run loop using this value as the mode are monitored by all run loop modes that have been declared as a member of the set of “common" modes; see the description of CFRunLoopAddCommonMode for details.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.